# How to Embed Youtube-dl in a Python Script

Tags: python, embed, youtube-dl

I'm trying to write a Python Script that downloads videos from youtube, and to do this I'm trying to use [youtube-dl](https://ytdl-org.github.io/youtube-dl/index.html).  However, when I insert the code in my python script on their github page that is supposed to embed the code

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import youtube_dl

ydl_opts = {}
with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    ydl.download(['https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BaW_jenozKc'])
```

my terminal spits out 'ImportError: No module named 'youtube_dl'

What does this mean and how do I allow my script to access the youtube-dl module?  I'm guessing this has something to do with locating the original path I downloaded youtube_dl to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the module first.

You can do this by using the command `pip install youtube_dl` in your terminal.

If pip in not installed, follow these guidelines: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/

Comment: Do I have to install it in the same directory that my script is located in?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [yt-dlp](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp) instead, it is a youtube-dl fork with additional features and fixes, it's awesome.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).